# Plotting block data in 3d using different colors and smoothing the lines in Gnuplot or Octave

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I am trying to plot (with Gnuplot) some basic 3d data from one file which is pretty much like that:

```
N     M    t1      t2       t3       t4
1000 1000 0.05268 0.04711 0.003947 0.003348
1000 2000 0.05743 0.04214 0.007577 0.006486
1000 3000 0.08465 0.04193 0.011329 0.009654


2000 1000 0.10726 0.08845 0.013593 0.012397
2000 2000 0.21065 0.10817 0.026525 0.024390
2000 3000 0.31528 0.16960 0.039772 0.036405


3000 1000 0.25415 0.14845 0.031082 0.026364
3000 2000 0.47345 0.25227 0.060887 0.051840
3000 3000 0.70612 0.36866 0.091311 0.077432
```

The idea is to plot it in some way I could see t1,t2,t3 and t4 for each N and M. It may be a lot of data to plot in only one graph, I know that. First of all, I have started with t1 plotting this way:

```
splot 'aux' u 1:2:3 w lp
```

and I get something like that[image]

I would like to smooth a bit those lines and give them a different color. Is there any way to do something for it? Also any ideas to improve it in any other way would be very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, that is a lot of data.  Changing the color of a particular dataset is pretty easy:

```
splot "dataset" using 1:2:3 w lines linecolor rgb "green"
```

Note that you can easily overlay multiple plots as follows:

```
splot "dataset" using 1:2:3 w lines lc rgb "green",\
      ""        using 1:2:4 w lines lc rgb "red"
```

A backslash at the end of a line is the gnuplot line-continuation character.  Note that it must be *the last character* on the line.  I've also used the pseudo-file `""` which is just shorthand for the last file that gnuplot read.  Finally, in this second version I used `lc` instead of `linecolor`.   The gnuplot parser provides a lot of shorthand, although I suspect you already know this since you plotted `w lp`.  (Also, please don't actually choose red and green for your plots.  I think one of the biggest flaws in gnuplot is the default first 2 colors are red and green -- 1 in 20 people is red-green colorblind)

Smoothing is another story (unfortunately).  `plot` does support a `smooth` option

```
plot "dataset" using 1:2 smooth beizer with lines  #see help smooth for a list of options
```

Unfortunately, it appears that this option doesn't work for `splot`.  At this point, I would write a small utility script to smooth the data in your favorite language using your favorite smoothing algorithm  (`plot "<utility.script mydata" u 1:2:3 ...`).  There are other (gnuplot-only) options, but they'd be ugly.  What version of gnuplot do you have by the way?  The gnuplot version is important to decide the best way to do the smoothing all in gnuplot if you decide that's still necessary.

Comment: You are just very right about the red and green colors...I've got Gnuplot version 4.0. Thanks for the advice and help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Manolete -- 4.0!  I'd say it's time for an upgrade ;-)

Comment: What could I get from a new version? Any cool features or options?

Comment: @Manolete -- Lots of new features, terminals, etc.  (I personally would have a hard time managing without at least 4.2, preferably 4.3).  But, it really depends on the types of plots you're making.  If you're just plotting lines and points, you might not notice the difference...